# Why aren't simulated events firing on a React module included as a dependency?

Tags: reactjs, testing, events, dependencies

I'm refactoring a large React project (https://github.com/bootstrapworld/codemirror-blocks) into modules, into a core library which is included and extended by the other modules (e.g. - https://github.com/bootstrapworld/pyret-blocks).

I have a large test suite in the monolithic repo, which passes just fine. In the refactored setup, those same tests fail when they involve simulated (via React-TestUtils) key events.

Some debugging is showing that these events aren't being received by the core library *at all*. The event handlers simply don't get called at all. However, running the actual app works just fine, with all real events being handled correctly.

There aren't any error messages - Karma tests just fail, with no output (other than the Karma test failure):

```
HeadlessChrome 76.0.3809 (Mac OS X 10.14.6) functions with return annotations fun g() -> Number: 2 * 4 end should activate function name, arguments, return annotation and body FAILED
    Error: Expected fun g() -> Number: 2 * 4 end not to be fun g() -> Number: 2 * 4 end. Tip: To check for deep equality, use .toEqual() instead of .toBe().
        at <Jasmine>
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (webpack:///spec/languages/pyret/Navigation-test.js:334:39 <- spec/index.js:42196:39)
        at <Jasmine>
        at asyncGeneratorStep (spec/index.js:41880:103)
    Error: Expected fun g() -> Number: 2 * 4 end to be g. Tip: To check for deep equality, use .toEqual() instead of .toBe().
        at <Jasmine>
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (webpack:///spec/languages/pyret/Navigation-test.js:335:35 <- spec/index.js:42197:35)
        at <Jasmine>
        at asyncGeneratorStep (spec/index.js:41880:103)
    Error: Expected fun g() -> Number: 2 * 4 end not to be fun g() -> Number: 2 * 4 end. Tip: To check for deep equality, use .toEqual() instead of .toBe().
        at <Jasmine>
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (webpack:///spec/languages/pyret/Navigation-test.js:359:39 <- spec/index.js:42219:39)
        at <Jasmine>
        at asyncGeneratorStep (spec/index.js:41880:103)
    Error: Expected fun g() -> Number: 2 * 4 end to be Number. Tip: To check for deep equality, use .toEqual() instead of .toBe().
        at <Jasmine>
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (webpack:///spec/languages/pyret/Navigation-test.js:361:35 <- spec/index.js:42221:35)
        at <Jasmine>
        at asyncGeneratorStep (spec/index.js:41880:103)
    Error: Expected fun g() -> Number: 2 * 4 end not to be fun g() -> Number: 2 * 4 end. Tip: To check for deep equality, use .toEqual() instead of .toBe().
        at <Jasmine>
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (webpack:///spec/languages/pyret/Navigation-test.js:371:39 <- spec/index.js:42229:39)
        at <Jasmine>
        at asyncGeneratorStep (spec/index.js:41880:103)
    Error: Expected fun g() -> Number: 2 * 4 end to be 2 * 4. Tip: To check for deep equality, use .toEqual() instead of .toBe().
        at <Jasmine>
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (webpack:///spec/languages/pyret/Navigation-test.js:374:35 <- spec/index.js:42232:35)
        at <Jasmine>
        at asyncGeneratorStep (spec/index.js:41880:103)
```

Comment: Is there any way you could try and share some of the results or code that we can work with? Not the whole project...

Comment: I know it's annoying to not have a reduced test case, but this is a complex project and I'm not actually sure which parts to cut out in order to reproduce the bug.  The test results aren't likely to be helpful, because all they do is provide a detailed account of why the test failed -- and the test failed because the key event it was supposed to evaluate never fired. Nevertheless, I'll add it to the OP.